# Capistrano is installed but cap command not found

Tags: ruby, symfony, rubygems, capistrano

I installed capistrano vía `gem install capistrano`, but when I run `cap install` to initialize a project, that command outputs:

`command not found: cap`

Previously I installed ruby 2.6.5p114 with `brew install ruby` and updated my path to new version, this is in a MacOS version 10.14.6

I want to deploy a Symfony4 project, any idea about what step I'm missing?

Comment: try `bundle exec cap install`

Comment: thanks, I didn't know how to execute the cap command

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruby Gem's may not be as consistent as the use of Composer. I use Capistrano to deploy a number of my own sites (including Symfony), and mostly followed the instructions on the capistrano-symfony page: https://github.com/capistrano/symfony/

1. Write the Gemfile
2. Install, with `bundle install`
3. Run: `bundle exec cap install`
4. Edit the capistrano config, and run with `bundle exec cap prod deploy` to use the configurations at config/deploy.rb & config/deploy/prod.rb

Comment: Step 3 was the one I was missing, thank you very much!